# ASP.Net Masterpage and Page viewstate

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, viewstate

If I have an asp.net page based on a viewpage, if I populate the viewstate in the page, is that value available in the master page? Or are they treated as two seperate collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Master pages and content pages do not share the same `ViewState`. If you need to pass information between these, you can use the `Session` object, `Context.Items` or create properties on the Master Page and access these.

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that there are strongly typed master pages which allow accessing the properties without further casting. Please use those:)

Comment: [does] not share the same `ViewState` may be too broad a statement to be wholly accurate. They don't share the same ViewState bag, but 'disabling' the ViewState on the content page supresses the SaveViewState call on the MasterPage. override the SaveViewState method on both Master and Content pages and verify it, by disabling this content page using page directive.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the `Context.Items` for me please a little more.

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to have a look at ServerVarialbes, as that might prove helpful in your case.